# Dataframe modification

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I would like to modify an existing data frame, of four columns.

However, only one of those columns will be modified, by dividing each number in it by 5.

I haven't found a way to run a for loop on only that column while keeping the rest of the data frame the same. Please give suggestions!

Comment: Don’t use a loop!  `df$x <- df$x/5`.

Comment: thanks! now i want to change the name of that one column for the purpose of the new data frame. how do i do this ?

Comment: `names(df)[ind] <- "newname"` where `ind` is the integer index of that column. For instance, if `x` is the 5th column in the frame, then `names(df)[5] <- "newname"`.

Comment: Or if you want a new column (not changing the original `x`), then `df$newname <- df$x/5`.